# Does anyone have idea about creating switch like this.?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to create a switch similar to this in xamarin forms. Anybody, please provide me with an idea.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMtLz.png]

Comment: Do you want it to work like how a switch works in android?

Comment: You can customize the `UI` with two buttons and perform your actions such as change the `backgroundColor` in the `Clicked` Event.

Comment: @Suriya - You can check out my this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630713/how-to-add-content-view-in-segment-control-in-xamarin-forms/53645711#53645711

Answer (score 2):

This is called Segmented Control in Xamarin.Forms. To create this we need to add  [Plugin.SegmentedControl.Netstandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.SegmentedControl.Netstandard/)  nuget packages. This looks same in android & iOS projects.

In your xaml file prefix this controll as `control:SegmentedControl`. For more information visit [Segmented Control In Xamarin.Forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/segment-control-in-xamarin-forms/)
.

Comment: I don't think he is asking for this

Comment: @G.hakim - If someone asking about Xamarin.Forms it means they need nearly same functionality for both platforms. When they don't have any option they'll go for custom renderer.

Comment: I am not talking about custom renderers I am talking about the fact that he said `SWITCH` i don't think he might be asking for a segmented control!! Is what I understood here maybe he just wants a regular switch getting my point?

Comment: I got your point. But I think OP used word switch, because OP might not know the correct name of the control. :)

Comment: I understand your point sir but it is always better to be sure what the user wants before answering the question it's pointless to get negative marked for no apparent reason if you know what I mean. :)

Comment: Hi Is there any option available to design the UI without using this plugin.

Comment: @Suriya - You can use plugin it provide so many facilities. There should not be any reason for not using plugin. Otherwise you need to use switch button as G. Hakim was talking about.