# How to add content view in segment control in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uisegmentedcontrol

I have to implement a content view in segment control. This is the UI I have to implement

[image]

As you can see there is two content view that is VENDOR NAME and PRODUCT/SERVICE. I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631238/how-to-add-content-page-to-segment-control-in-ios-xamarin-forms) and implemented it in iOS but in android, it's just a blank app. This is my XAML code.

```
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SegmentedApp" x:Class="SegmentedApp.SegmentedAppPage" >

    </ContentPage>

This is the code behind
 public partial class SegmentedAppPage : ContentPage
    {
        SegmentedControl segControl;
        SegmentedControlOption scOptionOne;
        SegmentedControlOption scOptionTwo;

        Grid grid;

        View1 view1 = new View1();
        View2 view2 = new View2();

        public SegmentedAppPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            segControl = new SegmentedControl();
            segControl.SelectedValue = "One";
            scOptionOne = new SegmentedControlOption();
            scOptionTwo = new SegmentedControlOption();

            scOptionOne.Text = "One";
            scOptionTwo.Text = "Two";

            segControl.Children.Add(scOptionOne);
            segControl.Children.Add(scOptionTwo);

            grid = new Grid();
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

            grid.Children.Add(segControl, 0, 0);
            grid.Children.Add(view1, 0, 1);

            this.Content = grid;

            segControl.ValueChanged += SegControl_ValueChanged;
        }

        private void SegControl_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SegmentedControl control = sender as SegmentedControl;
            if (control.SelectedValue is "One")
            {
                grid.Children.Remove(view2);
                grid.Children.Add(view1, 0, 1);  //This line 
            }
            else if (control.SelectedValue is "Two")
            {
                grid.Children.Remove(view1);
                grid.Children.Add(view2, 0, 1); //This line 
            }
            this.Content = grid;
        }
    }
```

This is my view1

```
public View1()
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
                Children = {
                new Label { Text = "View1" }
            }
            };
        }
```

I didn't find a custom renderer for this. I don't know how should I implement the custom renderer for this segment control. This is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sdvLBJRYyH31sVFTE6ae7xPTInN_X-qC/view?usp=sharing) for my project.

Comment: If possible provide your project link.

Comment: Yeah, I have mentioned the project link at the end.

Comment: But that is not opening. Provide after deleting bin and obj folders to reduce size.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 I have put the latest link. I removed the file from the bin and obj folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post you are following is focusing for iOS not for android. From custom render it probably going to show you radio button on android & for iOS same as above. To set up  [custom renderer](https://github.com/chrispellett/Xamarin-Forms-SegmentedControl/blob/master/Android/SegmentedControlRenderer.cs) you need to write up huge code including layout, styles & renderer class.

To reduce our work we can use [SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin](https://github.com/alexrainman/SegmentedControl). Just install it from Nuget package manager on solution level & write below code.

**`SegmentAppPage.xaml`** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
             x:Class="SegmentedApp.SegmentedAppPage" >

    <StackLayout x:Name="segContainer"
                 Padding="12"
                 Spacing="12">
        <controls:SegmentedControl BackgroundColor="White" SelectedTextColor="White" TintColor="#007AFF" x:Name="SegControl" ValueChanged="Handle_ValueChanged">
            <controls:SegmentedControl.Children>
                <controls:SegmentedControlOption  Text="Vender Name" />
                <controls:SegmentedControlOption Text="Product/Service" />
            </controls:SegmentedControl.Children>
        </controls:SegmentedControl>
        <StackLayout x:Name="SegContent" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Above we have declared `control` by using `namespace` of plugin. You can add `controls` as many children you need. In our case we need two buttons.

**`SegmentAppPage.xaml.cs`** file

```
public partial class SegmentedAppPage : ContentPage
{
    View1 view1 = new View1();
    View2 view2 = new View2();
    public SegmentedAppPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    void Handle_ValueChanged(object sender, SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin.Abstractions.ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.NewValue)
        {
            case 0:
                SegContent.Children.Clear();
                SegContent.Children.Add(view1);
                break;
            case 1:
                SegContent.Children.Clear();
                SegContent.Children.Add(view2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output screen:

[image]

Comment: So @CGPA6.4 there is no need of custom renderer in this?

Comment: No problem it worked with out the custom renderer. Thanks alot @CGPA6.4 your amazing. Bro fist!!!!

Comment: @user3452 - Happy coding ‍

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for Problem**

You currently have not implemented a custom renderer for the android platform and therefor will not see the same segmented controls and children of the segmented controls render.

**A Solution to your Problem**

In a previous app I developed I came across a similar problem and used the following plugin to solve the issue on both Android and iOS:

https://github.com/alexrainman/SegmentedControl

If you install the Nuget package SegmentedControl by alexrainman in your project and follow his documentation you will get it to work.

This cuts out the need for you to implement your own custom renderers on both platforms.

Please note:

your SegControl_ValueChanged method will change to Handle_ValueChanged

You should remove your current custom renderers for the iOS platform as not to cause confusion

Comment: Will that android custom renderer work for me because it shows the selection of radio button in the custom renderer code.

Comment: I need to implement a custom renderer which shows two content view as tabbed page.

Comment: Yes of course, it will work with your current target as you currently just have a grid with a seg control and second row for a view. The method SegControl_ValueChanged simply swaps the view relating to the segment that has just been activated, into view. The package I reference above contains all of that functionality :)

Comment: I have added that custom renderer but still, it is showing blank app.

Comment: Remove the custom renderers and install the Nuget package. The custom renderer in this package most probably conflicts with your forms code on the top level which is why you are seeing a blank page.

Comment: 1.) Remove all custom renderers you have implemented.
2.) Install Nuget Package above
3.) Follow instructions on github page.